# Connect more accounts to e-mail client

Tags: pantheon-mail

I have 4 different e-mail accounts (don't even ask…), and I wonder is there a way to connect all accounts to the default e-mail client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is, you can setup multiple mail accounts in Pantheon Mail.

Menu / Accounts (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>) and with `+` you can add a new account.

[image]

Comment: Thanks man, I probably tried every button instead of the Settings one, I feel kinda dumb...